# MATLAB Basics - interpreting parentheses and colons in array manipulation

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

What does it mean in MATLAB when I do:

```
array = array (1:number)
```

and what does it mean:

```
array = array(indexes_array)
```

and finally, what does it mean:

```
array = array(indexes_array,:)
```

Comment: Read here: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html -- or in the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html

Comment: Thanks, that totally solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Answers, according to MATLAB docs:

1)

```
array = array (1:number)
```

The colon notation in MATLAB provides an easy way to extract a range of elements from v:

```
v(3:7)     % Extract the third through the seventh elements
  ans =
        9   4   2   11   7
```

2)

```
array = array(indexes_array)
```

`array` is reorganized according to `indexes_array` order, assuming that  `indexes_array` is composed of indexes.

3)

```
array = array(indexes_array,:)
```

just the same as number 1), `array` is reorganized according to all the rows of `indexes_array`, ignoring the columns.

**References:** 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html
https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html